# Android app starts scanning QR code via QR Droid v7.0 -- gets null result

Tags: android, qr-code

My app starts QR Droid to scan URL texts. Works in my case very well, so I would like to stay with QRdroid.

Since having another Android 7 mobile device, the very same code gives no text result. I start QR Droid via:

```
Intent qrDroid = new Intent("la.droid.qr.scan");
// optionally qrDroid.putExtra("la.droid.qr.complete", true);
try {
   startActivityForResult(qrDroid, 0);
```

In the debugger I see that the value of qrDroid is:

> Intent { act=la.droid.qr.scan launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams{
>   mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0}}

The result is received in this method (either in the activity or the fragment):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

The values are:

- The requestCode = 64k ... a high number, not the 0 I used to start the intent.
- The requestResult = RESULT_OK (-1)
- The data is:

> Intent { act=la.droid.qr.scan flg=0x80000
>   launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams{ mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0}(has
>   extras)} mExtras = { Bundle@7198} "Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=340]

How can I get the text result (of the scanned URL) in my app?

Comment: Have you enabled camera-permissions for the QRdroid app? Did your previous device had a different Android version?

Comment: QR droid started and scanned the QR code. 
Also, I started the QR droid seperately - no problem at all. 
Previous device was Lineage Android 7.1.2.. Current one is Android 7.0.

Comment: after I upgraded QR droid from 6.8 to 7.0, there is no returned extras.. :/

Comment: @burgyna, so, you are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be issue with QR droid 7.0.
It works with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr.priva
You have just use   (l̶a̶̶̶.̶̶̶d̶̶̶r̶̶̶o̶̶̶i̶̶̶d̶̶̶.̶̶̶q̶̶̶r̶̶̶.̶̶̶p̶̶̶r̶̶̶i̶̶̶v̶̶̶a̶̶̶.̶̶̶D̶̶̶e̶̶̶C̶̶̶a̶̶̶m̶̶̶e̶̶̶r̶̶̶a̶̶̶  )  "la.droid.qr.scan" as launch intent.

Comment: Great - I will try. So getting the result is then also via getString( "a.droid.qr.priva.DeCamera")? 
Further options needed, like "Full/Complete"?

Comment: no, to get result use intent.getExtras().getString("la.droid.qr.result"). I have used Complete option, but it doesnt affect it.

Comment: I tried both new Intent( "la.droid.qr.priva.DeCamera") and  new Intent("la.droid.qr.priva") but it didn't start.

Comment: this is my code: Intent intent = new Intent("la.droid.qr.priva.DeCamera");
            intent.putExtra( "la.droid.qr.complete" , true);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_REQUEST_DROIDLA); It starts. If you have the app installed.

Comment: I can start it with "la.droid.qr.scan". Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Yes you are right. generally you can only start it with "la.droid.qr.scan". Only on my rooted device "la.droid.qr.priva.DeCamera" worked.